# Given $\int_a^b f(x)x^{2n+1}dx=0$ determine $f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Let $a\leq b$, and $N\in\mathbb{N}$:

'If $\int_a^b f(x)x^{2n+1}dx=0$ for each integer $n\geq N$, then $f=0$on $[a,b]$.'

Argue truth or false:

(a) $N=0$, $[a,b]=[0,1]$;

(b) $N=1$, $[a,b]=[0,1]$;

(c) $N=0$, $[a,b]=[-1,1]$.

*Another question:

I have seen the proof for if $\int_a^b f(x)x^n dx=0$ for $n\geq 0$, then $f=0$ on such an interval. It seemed like it doesn't depends on the domain. Does the domain matter?why?

Comment: Consider (c). If $f(x)$ is even then $f(x)x^{2n+1}$ is odd so $\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)x^{2n+1}dx=0$... so that's not true that $f(x)=0 \ \ \forall x\in[-1,1]$

Comment: Do you know the Muntz-Szasz theorem?

Comment: I don't know why in (b) $N=1$ :\ I don't see difference with (a).

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг no...

Comment: Then do read it up. It says exactly when a set of powers of the variable is dense in the space of continuous functions on a closed interval under the current norm.

Comment: @lxion What if $x\in[-1,2]$? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ixion remarked, (c) is false as one can take $f$ to be any even function.

In (a) and (b) a change of variable gives $\int_0^1 f(\sqrt y)y^n\,dy=0$.
Set $F(y)=f(\sqrt y)$. In (a) use the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem to approximate $F$ by a polynomial. Can you adapt this trick for (b)?

Comment: What's the difference between $\int_a^bf(x)x^ndx=0$ and $\int_0^1f(x)x^ndx=0$ given true for all $n\geq 0$?

Comment: Shouldn't $f(x)=0$ where $x$ is contained in the domain for both cases?